# How to vertically align text inside <li> in a CSS based drop-down menu?

Tags: css

Can someone take a look at this menu http://www.abmoldremediationnj.com/3 and let me know how to vertically align links in drop down? If you need me to post a code here I could, and I know its very messy.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code so people in the far future will be able to see what you meant, in case that link no longer works.

Comment: my code is so messy I am ashamed to post it here :(

Comment: well, it's much harder to get better if you don't allow others to look at your code, and this question is effectively useless if your link ever goes down. Put your pride away so that you and others can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `line-height` rule for `#menus ul li a` which targets links in drop down too. So 45px line-height in a 26px height parent can't be rendered fine.

Change `line-height` for links in drop down with `#menus ul ul a` eg.

Comment: God bless you, I spent 6 hours trying to fix it yesterday, and you show me a single line of code to make my problems go away!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in your `#menus ul li ul li` remove `height:26px;`